# Is there an equivalent in Angular JS of props from React JS?

Tags: angularjs, reactjs, react-props

I am learning angularJS and I was wondering if there is the equivalent of props like there is in react. More specifically, a way to add  with props that I define in another file. It would make the website I'm coding in angular much more efficient but I can't find the equivalent in Angular.

Comment: it's not really clear what you are asking here;  the concepts between reactjs and angularjs are totally different, and it's not exactly obvious where you would expect something like props to be used.  What does "a way to add with props that I define in another file" mean?  Add **what??**

Comment: AngularJS especially is a much older framework, written well before React was a glimmer in some Facebook developer's eye. Angular (a different framework with a similar name but a much different internal structure) is closer in timeline, but again has a different architecture than React.

Comment: @Claies isn't it well explained in my post? Sorry if i didn't make it clear. So in react you can define props for example const names = props => { const {firstname, lastname, initials} = props ... then you can have some jsx and use dynamic elements by calling {props.firstname}, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a way to do something similar in AngularJS. It is called Directives. In your case you want to create a directive with `restrict` set to `'E'`.
`'E'` tells the compiler that it will be an element in the generated HTML.

```js
angular.module('scopeDirective', [])
.controller('app', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.naomi = { name: 'Uriel', address: '1600 Amphitheatre' };
  $scope.igor = { name: 'Bitton', address: '123 Somewhere' };
}])
.directive('customer', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      customerInfo: '=info'
    },
    templateUrl: 'customer.html'
  };
});
```

The `scope` object after `restrict` defines the various attributes you would want this directive to accept. This is similar to how props work in React. In that object, you can see `customerInfo` which corresponds to the directive's isolate scope property. The value `(=info)` tells `$compile` to bind to the info attribute.
The `templateUrl` maps to the HTML for this directive.

Using the above directive will look something like below:

```html
<div ng-controller="app">
  <customer info="uriel"></customer>
  <hr>
  <customer info="bitton"></customer>
</div>
```

Kindly refer to the AngularJS docs on [Directives](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive).

> NOTE: Instead of trying to do something in AngularJS that is similar to how you do things in React or any other framework/library, I would suggest you do not instead embrace the current framework's capability and use it as is without trying to compare way of achieving similar things as this can lead to frustration down the road.

I hope you find this answer useful for your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Is it not the same as using `@Input() info:string` in the component and when its being used

`<component [info] = "string">`

?

in react it would be `{props.info}` in the component

and then `<component info="something">` when its being used